# Hardware acceleration of Chrome's Flash plugin

Tags: google-chrome, flash, hardware-acceleration

Running Flash in Google Chrome drains my CPU massively:

[image]

I figured that the cause of this issue would be that hardware acceleration of flash is turned off. When I tried turning it by right clicking a flash application and selecting `settings`, this window popped up:

[image]

No hardware acceleration options can be found.

In Chrome, when I open `about:gpu`, I get to see this:

[image]

How do I turn hardware acceleration on in Flash or is there an alternative way of reducing the CPU usage?

Comment: You should check this [bug](http://crbug.com/137247), this [bug](http://crbug.com/145600) and this [bug](http://crbug.com/133828). Also, updated my answer with more verbose instructions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should check your `about:gpu` section in Chrome/ium. In older PC's HW Acceleration is disabled by default and you only can enable it by overriding the settings in the `about:flags`.

- Open the `about:flags` in your address bar
- Look for **Override software redendering list**
- Click "Enable"
- Restart Chrome/ium

You can also start chrome using `chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist` but having to do so each time is not ideal.

[image: This is my GPU page]

[image: THis is my flags]

Comment: That was useful, although I found that enabling **Override software rendering list** in `about:flags` is not sufficient to enable a lot of those features including HW accelerated video decoding. For some reason passing the flag via the command line using `chromium-browser --ignore-gpu-blacklist` seems to work.

Comment: Seems to be related to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509336

Answer (score 2):

Try `LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 google-chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist` if you end up here looking for a solution on a version affected by a [LibGL DRI bug on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Iteration+ReleaseBlock+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&cells=tiles).

Comment: Thanks! This works for my problem that chromium gave the error `libGL error: DRI3 Fence object allocation failure Operation not permitted`, so no hardware acceleration at all was available. The method I had been using was to disable the GPU sandbox as described [here](http://keithp.com/blogs/chromium-dri3/) *(using `chromium --ignore-gpu-blacklist --disable-gpu-sandbox`)*, but your method doesn't generate the annoying warning banner :)