# Google Chrome themes are not transparent

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, google-chrome, transparency

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and Google Chrome version 28.0.1500.71 (the latest as of this writing).

There are a lot of themes with transparency in the Chrome Web Store, but they never work on my system. What kind of configuration am I missing to make transparent themes work in Chrome?

Here is an example of a [theme that should be transparent but is not](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ubuntu-black-magic-theme/hnoinlancgjpkamgbmmahlekaecighkk?hl=en):

[image]

On my system (the dark gray title-bar is not transparent):

[image]

From my `about:gpu` page (*before enabling flags and messing with stuff*):

[image]

`about:gpu` page (*after messing with stuff*)

[image]

Comment: Check your `about:gpu` page. It may be that you don't have hardware acceleration enabled, or chrome don't detects it correctly, ergo you don't get transparencies.

Comment: I added a screencap of that page to my post.

Comment: Try the solutions offered [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/325433/169736). Remember to restart the browser.

Comment: Hmm, I am still unable to have transparent themes on Ubuntu. I have changed the settings as you described,  switched back to default Chrome theme and re-installed new transparent themes with no luck.  I have also tried enabling additional relevant settings in the `about:flags` page. One last thing: I have installed the latest driver from NVIDIA for 64-bit Linux for my graphics card. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: I found that it's because the theme depends on some `gtk2` (as the theme suggest in a link in the description) functions not present in `gtk3` and that's why it fails. I've tried in my Debian 7 and failed too. So, the theme(s) is too old or chrome don't support the transparency in newer systems.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Braiam in comments:

> I found that it's because the theme depends on some gtk2 (as the theme suggest in a link in the description) functions not present in gtk3 and that's why it fails. I've tried in my Debian 7 and failed too. So, the theme(s) is too old or chrome don't support the transparency in newer systems.