# Processor temperature when just browsing the web is 55-60 C

Tags: temperature, cpu

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. It has an `Intel® Core™ i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4`, 8 GB ram, and an `AMD Radeon HD 8730M` It also has a `Intel HD 4000` but i'm using `AMD`
I have nothing else open than `Chromium`, A `terminal`, and `konversation` and CPU temp is 55-60 C or even more sometimes. When I run a 3D game it goes up to 80-85 and again sometimes even more. In `Windows 8` tho... temp is at 54 C most of the time. Is this normal? If not, is there something I can do about it or  this is strictly hardware related problem? (if it's a problem). Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've got a laptop with a similar config (an nvidia discrete gpu instead of amd), and used to face the same cooling issues as you until I started using TLP- which is a command line power management tool for linux. Here are the steps to isntall it : http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

I also use bumblebee which helped reduce my idle temps. by around 5-7 degrees, though its only for nvidia optimus laptops. I'm pretty sure there's a similar tool for amd switchable graphics.

Comment: I installed TLP and it did decrease temp by a few degrees, now I'm looking for a Bumblebee like program for AMD. I really hope there's one. If you run 3D programs how high does the temp go?

Comment: Dude!!! Thank you very much. I'm running the 3D game that I was talking about and CPU temp just went up like 5 degrees!!! with 3d graphics running temperature is at 60C and without at 55-57 C somtimes dropping to 50. If you have more tips about temperature please share :) THANK YOU! +1

Answer (score 0):

This temperature is absolutely normal. You should start to worry if the temperature reaches  70-80 when 'just browsing the web'.

Also keep in mind that flash applications can eat your CPU. See [Hardware acceleration of Chrome's Flash plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325431/hardware-acceleration-of-chromes-flash-plugin) for info on reducing CPU usage (thus temperature height) when using flash applications.

Comment: Well... I just logged in ubuntu and one of the cores is at 75 - 80 c when just browsing the net o_O... is that still normal? Average temp is 73 or something. I've read threads about people running at 40 C. I don't find this normal.