# How can I enable hardware acceleration for flash on Intel graphics?

Tags: graphics, flash, adobe

Is there any way to improve the Adobe flash player hardware acceleration in Ubuntu, with an Intel graphics card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using libvdpau-va-gl is a VDPAU driver  we can accelerate the flash player in terms of increasing its decoding speed.

To install it and configure the instruction are here . Open your terminal and type as 
To install the latest Intel Drivers( if already installed , no need)

```
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
```

Then install libvdpau-va-gl

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libvdpau-va-gl1
```

instruct the adobe flash for hardware acceleration

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/adobe
echo "EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=1" | sudo tee /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
echo "OverrideGPUValidation=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
```

suggest your browser for acceleration

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox
```

*Note: chrome was not up to this.*

That's it. your flash will be fast more than usual.

[credit goes](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/adobe-flash-player-hardware.html)

Comment: For the Chrome/Chromium browsers see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/325431/178596)