# How can I confirm that I'm using Adobe Flash hardware acceleration (VDPAU) with Chrome on Ubuntu with integrated Intel card HD4xxx and default driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, google-chrome, flash, intel-graphics

The title tells it all. I have found one similar question but it is outdated from 2013 and not related to Chrome.

[How can I enable hardware acceleration for flash on Intel graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342600/how-can-i-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-flash-on-intel-graphics)

When I go to chrome://gpu it gives me this:

[image: Output from Chrome://gpu]

However, it also says that video decode is unavailable:

[image: Output from Chrome://gpu]

How can I be sure that I'm using my GPU for Flash on Google Chrome, which is the only way to use Flash on Ubuntu since Adobe droped support for Linux?

[image: Adobe Flash support and versions]

When I do right click on a flash video, 'Enable hardware acceleration' is on.

[image]