# Can I get hardware acceleration working for video (H.264) in firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, gpu, hardware-acceleration, h264

My CPU is always maxing out and fans going crazy whenever I watch streaming video on Firefox.

visiting `about:support`, I see `Hardware H264 Decoding:    No`, despite Firefox otherwise recognising my Intel GPU.

Looking at a couple of Mozilla bugs, it looks like maybe they don't actually support hardware acceleration for video, is that correct?  Is there any way to get hardware video acceleration for Firefox on Ubuntu?

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563206

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1210727

Comment: PS, in Chrome, [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/325431/hardware-acceleration-of-chromes-flash-plugin) got me hardware acceleration. fans still going nuts, but only 30% CPU instead of 200+